# Configuring Visual Studio 2022 to develop Python projects in WSL2

Tags: python, visual-studio, wsl-2

I installed WSL2 and use Visual Studio (VS) 2022 on the windows. I want to configure my VS 2022, so I can develop Python projects in WLS2. All tutorials I find online only talks about visual studio code. I don't want to install another IDE. Does anybody know how to do that or point me to some material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not at this time, no.  The VSCode integration with WSL is done through the use of an extension that creates an interop server between Windows VSCode and the Linux side of WSL.  There isn't an extension like that for Visual Studio, however.

The only WSL integration that I'm aware of in Visual Studio 2022 is the inclusion of a WSL toolchain that allows you to target WSL/Linux in C++ projects.  But nothing that I'm aware of for Python, no.

I believe you'll need to install an additional IDE to get Python/WSL support, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if VS is available for Linux or WSL2 yet.

If you look at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/, only Windows & Mac seem to be supported.

So you have 2 main options:

1. Use VS on Windows itself. Then you just need to install the Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS) to be able to support Python development
2. Use VS Code on WSL2 - it's pretty lightweight to install anyway as a code editor, but can be endowed with comparable features to VS

EDIT: It may be that I'm misunderstanding the question as pointed out below by NotTheDr01ds, and instead you want to target WSL2 from the VS IDE, developing Python.

Comment: That's not really what's being asked here.  The question is whether Visual 2022 for *Windows* supports (or can be configured for) *integration* with WSL2 for Python projects, similar to what the *Windows* version of VSCode does.

Comment: Also just a heads-up that Python support in Visual Studio 2022 is not available in Mac at the moment.  Not all that important as far as the question goes, but you mentioned that Mac is supported, which it is not for Python development in VS2022.

Comment: It might be that I'm misinterpreting the initial question, and your interpretation is correct - i.e., that the intention is to use VS as the IDE targeting WSL2 for development. As the current title is worded however, it can be taken to understood (or misunderstood) to mean if it's possible install VS & develop Python all within WSL2. So I'll leave my answer as-is, in case anyone else has a similar (mis)interpretation.

Comment: That's why we answer the *question body* and not the title ;-).  The body specifically states that the OP, "use(s) Visual Studio (VS) 2022 on ... Windows" and doesn't "want to install another IDE".